# Combine table column into single string (without UDF)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, concatenation

I'm trying to combine a field from multiple records **into a single string** in SQL Server or T-SQL.

> ***For example***, I have:
>
> ```
>  ID   myString
>  1    This
>  2    is
>  3    a
>  4    test!
> ```
>
> ...and ***I need***:  `This is a test!`

**I can combine two records** using [**LAG**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (see below), and I suspect there's a [**WHILE**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the solution (maybe a variation of [this RedGate post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)), but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
create table #temp (id int, myString varchar(max));
  insert into #temp values (1,'This');
  insert into #temp values (2,'is');
  insert into #temp values (3,'a');
  insert into #temp values (4,'test!');

select 
  myString,
  LAG(myString) OVER (ORDER BY id) + ' ' + myString as [myTwoFields]
from #temp
```

*...returns:*

```
ID   myString   myTwoFields  
 1     This
 2     is        This is
 3     a         is a
 4     test!     a test!
```

Unfortunately, **I can't create UDF's** on this server.  Therefore, SE Data Explorer is a representative place for testing:

> See [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/847299/test-combine-column-into-single-string-without-udf) on SEDE, or you can **[click here to fork it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/847299)** for testing.

*Thoughts?  Thanks!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select NewStr = Stuff((Select ' ' +MyString From #temp Order by ID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

**Returns**

```
NewStr
This is a test!
```

**Another option**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = ''
Select @S = ltrim(@S+' '+MyString)
 From  #Temp
 Order by ID

Select @S
```

**Returns**

```
This is a test!
```

Comment: it's called **existing op**

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I'm sorry - what's called *existing op*?  (Google wasn't much help without context)

Comment: This is not the first problem

Comment: @ashleedawg This is a good answer, just to mention it: If your strings might include forbidden characters (like `<, > , &`) this would lead to strange output like `&lt;` instead of `<`. But you use this instead: `Stuff((Select ' ' +MyString From #temp Order by ID For XML Path (''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')`